# Logout function from AngularJS client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, restful-authentication

I am trying the following article to practice the login and register functions from client side using AngularJS and token-based authentication mechanism. However, the article does not mention how to handle logout and expired authentication token functions from client side using AngularJS.

My questions:
1) If I want to add a global HTML Logout button and if user presses that button, then how can I clear authentication token from client side Angular scripts as well as from the server side (.Net/C#)?

2) I set the valid period for the authentication token (from server side codes .NEt/C#) to 60 minutes. If the browser is idle (no user interactions at all) in 60 minutes or more, then how the user is automatically kicked the site and directed to the login page if he resumes his work on the browser after 60-or-more-minute-idle interval?

Thank you in advance.

**Article link:**

[Getting started with AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC - The long awaited Part Three](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/843044/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-The)

---

Some summary details about the token-based authentication the article author uses:

*POST token request body:*

grant_type: password
userName: email@email.com (or whatever you registered with)
password: Password1! (or whatever password you set when registering)

*And token response:*

{
    "access_token": "R-AejC88wImTKUulwlZBRsR620zXuHcrjV26UGObVjl5s9aqJIhs2hzt60CdLhL0hXNR-kyLTgrTfiMDV4JZJsmC1jV3MQHKcScsW6lYAMz1kegSyQiSfRHVj8W1E76x9uiHYJVIWhwA_RH7GkTn3K_Z0ugV_0qsSd1cWZ5qpqRedrS1vbHNIr7PR-FvAcKGA5c0S7ffadD8TP6N8OX8AyEg2t5rxppAeT2AlqlY3G5HdJqDkPgXQx5pL_xXRWkQCuOhIgUCm-6TDAksNf-EJ7HzPKD7nl7KU8Pd66rQO56p_vtq6eOO9OtgAmN8FviR-gNKGHCsz4udPrAKTExF_Ht4hBpbLoiGIXIbVUpzTeB-RMZUMMcRgByo4tCELjd41pV0mjaXHS6s7mTuwlgGmxiAU5AoYgNTXVOe9YegZMvjW_lAIUw0YlZ0m7RAiPOTTDlRzmV1ntm3YGvAN9h9_m027twqfGz5YsHsbh3RYW8",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 1209599,
    "userName": "email@email.com",
    ".issued": "Sun, 16 Nov 2014 22:55:45 GMT",
    ".expires": "Sun, 30 Nov 2014 22:55:45 GMT"
}

Comment: Where do you store the token in the client side? LocalStorage? You can remove it from there on the "Logout" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: as jpgrassi said, you can remove/set undefined the user token since you stored it (the example case: `SessionService.token`) on a "logout" event.

Q2: considering you know how to setup Owin, you can change the `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan` in the `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions`. 
Example:

```
...
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() {
  AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes) 
};
...
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I store the token using localStorage and clear it on user logging out.